# Conditional Logistic Regression - detailed examples

Tags: regression

anyone has online resources / book references that has detailed tutorials/examples on setting up Conditional Logistic Regression ? (Preferably in R, Matlab or Python)

Answer (score 2):

Look for **clogit** function in this [page](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/SocialSciences.html) (for R)

The function is described [here](http://bm2.genes.nig.ac.jp/RGM2/R_current/library/survival/man/clogit.html)

Examples can be found in this pdf: [Matched Case-Control Studies](http://www.biostat.uzh.ch/teaching/master/methods2009/eslides5.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You may find these two papers of use:

"Design and Analysis of Choice Experiments Using R: A Brief Introduction"
http://www.jstage.jst.go.jp/article/air/17/2/17_86/_article

"Introduction to choice experiments using R"
http://agris.fao.org/agris-search/search/display.do?f=./2008/JP/JP0814.xml;JP2007008140

You may need to go to your local library to access them...